# Google analytics history API for subdmomain

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics

I have a problem. I need to get visitors history from Google analytics for specific subdomain. Through their API. I cant find it in doc.

Have you ever been solving it and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to filter by hostname

filters=ga:hostname=~subdomain.domain.com

here is the documentation in dimension reference https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/pagetracking#ga:hostname